# Use ogr2ogr to get KML out of PostGIS

Tags: kml, ogr2ogr

I am trying to export a Postgis database table into KML using ogr2ogr.
When I execute this command in terminal (Ubuntu 12) I just get the "documentation" back but no result or error:

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" mykml.kml PG:"host=localhost user=**** dbname=nga_test password=***" "public.chalandri" -s_srs EPSG:2100 -t_src EPSG:4326
```

Is this normal?

Comment: it usually means that you have missed a parameter, try ogrinfo on the postgis DB to make sure you are accessing it correctly,

Comment: alternatively you might not have KML support built in, is KML in the list of formats you see?

Comment: PostGIS can generate KML directly http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsKML.html

Comment: Check `ogr2ogr --formats` and make sure KML is in there.